# encoding base64 and saving it to server javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, base64

I am trying to make it so that a user can upload an image and get the image encoded and saved into database and server. I do not have any experience with base64. I have the rest of my inputs saving, just cant figure out how to save image. my html code is

```
<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();"  
  accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" />
  <div id="imgTest"></div>
```

my javascript is as follows and i ge an error thatt prompts encodeImageFileAsURL() is not defined.

```
function encodeImageFileAsURL() {

var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

var fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
  var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

  var newImage = document.createElement('img');
  newImage.src = srcData;

  document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;
  alert("Converted Base64 version is " + 
document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
  console.log("Converted Base64 version is " + 
document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
  }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
  }
}
```

all help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Is your script called before your input ?

Comment: No my input is above my script

Comment: This is why. Try inserting your script before your input and see if it works.

Comment: Okay I did that and was successful. but it prompted an alert with the code to the client side with the code how do I get it to not alert and just log for a more user friendly website. Also when sending to my server what would be the best method to make it a variable that i could pass in ,y cloud code

Comment: Will I be able to use document.getElementById("#").value to save and send the code to my server?

Comment: To log, simply replace your alert() by console.log(). You will be able to save anything from the doc yes.

Comment: I appreciate both of you! I got it successfully saving to my database.